# How to convert text into formulas in Excel when referencing another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm working on a set of worksheets where I need to make a summation with more than one constraint parameter, so I use the function `sumifs ()`
It happens that the worksheet needs to consider the rows that are added and so this *sum with constraints* is constructed from the function `concatenate` whose parameters come from another worksheet.

So, trying to use the suggestion did not work ... or with

```
Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate (Ref)
```

So I need help since I don't know how to solve the issue, how to turn the text bellow into a formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("=SUMIFS(lançamentos!N$2:N";TEXT(L1+2;0);";lançamentos!AA$2:AA";TEXT(L1+2;0);";lançamentos!AA";TEXT(L1+4;0);";lançamentos!D2:D";TEXT(L1+2;0);";ADDRESS(ROW(A3);COLUMN(A3);4))")
```

Comment: maybe `INDIRECT` would be an alternative as you can construct adresses with it. But on big databases the workbook gets quite slow.

Comment: I think your issue is that you are using semi-colons.  I'm not 100% about this, but I think you would need to use commas in the code.  You could try `Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate (Replace(Ref,";",","))`